# How to instruct ESLint to ignore a ruleset in a project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

In my VSCode (Win 10) I have installed the [VSCode extension ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint).  On my computer is a Node project, with a JS file inside. If I open this JS file in VSCode, ESLint reports infractions from several different rule sets, including Prettier ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQoT5.jpg)).  For this project only, how can I instruct ESLint to *not* check any of the rules in the Prettier rule set?

FYI when I open VSCode, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwcul.jpg) is a list of the extensions installed.

The `.eslintrc.json` file for this project contains the following:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@wordpress/eslint-plugin/recommended"
  ],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jquery": true
  }
}
```

Note:  The plugin `@wordpress/eslint-plugin/recommended` is a separate plugin I have added to this project, and it has rules that I want ESLint to list and report.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Answer (score 2):

Inside eslintrc.js, you can omit/edit the rules you do not like, as such:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'airbnb-base',
  rules: {
    'no-console': 'off',
    'no-restricted-syntax': 'off',
    'linebreak-style': 0,
    'guard-for-in': 'off',
    'max-len': ['error', { code: 160 }],
  },
};
```

Comment: Right.  I'd have to omit rules on a rule-by-rule basis.  I'm looking for a way to omit all rules in a rule set.

Answer (score 0):

You can override such rules inside .eslintrc.json according to

```
{
    "extends": [
        ...
    ],
    ...
    "rules": {
      "<rule1>": "off",
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. But to do that I have to manually type out each rule in the Prettier rule set.  Is there a way to simply instruct ESLint to ignore that entire rule set?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can ignore rules from ESLint

1. Manually specify each rule in `.eslintrc` file as `off`

```
{
    "extends": [
        ...
    ],
    ...
    "rules": {
      "<rule1>": "off",
      ...
    }
}
```

2. [Ignore files or folder from eslint rules](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories) i.e. add `ignorePatterns`

```
{
    "ignorePatterns": ["temp.js", "**/vendor/*.js"],
    "rules": {
        //...
    }
}
```

3. Create `.eslintignore` file and exclude the files or folder from being linted by ESLint. [ESLint Ignore](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#eslintignore)

Comment: OK.  So is that to say that if I want to ignore all the rules in the Prettier rule set, I have to manually type out each of the rules in my `.eslintrc` file?